# Toshi browser vs. Google Chrome browser to interact with Dapp?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, javascript

Toshi is a browser to interact with Dapps such that after uploading our Dapp (including solidity smart contract, Javascript and HTML code) on a server, we can search our Dapp using its URL (ex: www.MyDapp.com). Then, we can invoke functions of our contract and send transaction.

Toshi Github: https://github.com/toshiapp/toshi-web/blob/master/README.md

Now, question is that is it possible to do this by Google Chrome instead of Toshi browser?  (of course without installing any Add-on on Google Chrome or installing any package on Android phone.)